# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with an array that is large enough to hold the data I give it

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I've made the following method:

```
static int GenerateSeccondPal(int x){
    String y = Integer.toString(x);
    char[] z1 = y.toCharArray();
    char[] z2 = new char[y.length() / 2];

    for (int count = (z1.length /2); count <= z1.length; count++) {
        z2[count] = z1[count];
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(new String(z2));

}
```

However, when I run it, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>       at challenges.Problem_4.GenerateSeccondPal(Problem_4.java:31)
>       at challenges.Problem_4.main(Problem_4.java:6)

Which is odd, because the other method I made:

```
static int GenerateFirstPal(int x) {
    String y = Integer.toString(x);
    char[] z1 = y.toCharArray();
    char[] z2 = new char[z1.length / 2];

    for (int count = 0; count < z1.length / 2; count++) {
        z2[count] = z1[count];
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(new String(z2));

}
```

Works perfectly. What is wrong with what I have written?

Comment: Why are you messing around with *strings* at all, when your input and output is really numeric? Do you really want to split 1234 into 12 and 34, but 123456 into 123 and 456?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have pointed out the array problems, but I don't see why you're using arrays at all. Just use `substring`:

```
static int generateFirstPal(int x) {
    String y = String.valueOf(x);
    String firstPart = y.substring(0, y.length() / 2);
    return Integer.parseInt(firstPart);
}

static int generateSecondPal(int x) {
    String y = String.valueOf(x);
    String secondPart = y.substring(y.length() / 2);
    return Integer.parseInt(secondPart);
}
```

Frankly this seems like an odd design anyway... are you *sure* this is the right behaviour in the first place? Given that you're dealing with numbers, it's not clear why you need a string representation at all. Depending on the expected length of the strings, I'd expect something like this:

```
static int generateFirstPal(int x) {
    return x / 1000;
}

static int generateSecondPal(int x) {
    return x % 1000;
}
```

This will split 123456 into 123 and 456, for example. Adjust the 1000 according to your real values.

Comment: Jon Skeet: Also awesome on independence day. Thanks for bringing the sanity.

Comment: Thanks =) I'm new to Java and have not learnt about sub strings yet, which is why I did not use them.

Comment: The reason I didn't do it the second way, is because the numbers are of varying length. 15 / 1000 doesn't equal 1.

Comment: @Deza: So you want the results for 99 to be very different to the results for 100? What exactly are these input values? This sounds like an odd pair of routines to me...

Comment: I'm trying to find out if a number is palindrome. I've managed it, you can see my code here: http://www.pastie.org/private/iee7kj7pdd1dxfniigosw

Comment: @Deza: That doesn't show palindromes. I think you've misunderstood the meaning of the word palindrome. For example, 1010 is *not* a palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<=` should probably be a `<` to avoid that exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your count variable is not starting from 0, so you have to rest the amount so that z2[count] starts from 0 in the for instead of starting from z1.length / 2

Comment: I changed it to: for (int count = 0; count < 14; count++) {
   if(count > (z1.length / 2)) {
   z2[count] = z1[count];
   }
  }, but still no luck.

Comment: you mean 14 as an example or are you sure the length of z2 will always be less or equal than 14?

Answer (score 0):

THe moment you do it:

```
for (int count = (z1.length /2); count <= z1.length; count++)
{ 
 z2[count] = z1[count];
}
```

Supposing z1.length is 7 and z2.length is 4 it means that your program will crash because z2 does not have an index 4, only 3 at maximum.

I think you should start your counter = 0 and iterate while count < z2.length if you want to copy the first positions of the first array to the second;